# 500 server error on clear cache

Tags: 7, caching

I am facing a pretty strange problem. I have installed Drupal 7 on my site. Whenever I install a module and tries to access the module's configure page after enabling the module, it leads me to simply /admin/config page without showing the option for that particular module configuration.

sometimes when I do a clear cache the problem gets resolved and then I can access the module's config page. but sometime after installing a module, clear cache gives Internal Server Error 500 .. also I tried to flush the cache manually by making a php file into / directory with the following code:

```
<?php
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
drupal_flush_all_caches();
?>
```

but this also gives Error 500.

When I disable the installed module, clear cache works as usual...
please help me.

Comment: What are the permissions on the root folder ?

Comment: @aerozeppelin  I am using shared hosting so can not set permissions on root folder, btw `.php` files are working when placed in root folder

Comment: I am not sure about this, but you could try increasing your php memory limit and then check if the problem still persists.

Comment: @aerozeppelin I have also tried by setting `ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');` in `settings.php` but problem remains the same

Comment: Try increasing it to 256M or 512M, and then check.

Comment: @aerozeppelin no effect :( tried with `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`   just to give more information, the 500 error page also comes up whenever I enable or disable a module (on loading http://<my-site>/admin/modules/list/confirm page)

Comment: Check your php error_logs, you may get some information there.

Comment: @aerozeppelin Can you please tell me where to find these logs.

Comment: It should be outside your drupal root folder. Probably inside a folder called logs. If you can't find it, check your php.ini file to know its path

Comment: Is this can be the cause as I am seeing this notice in the drupal logs after enabling the module `Notice: Undefined variable: errstr in drupal_http_request() (line 836 of /home/<path>/htdocs/includes/common.inc).`

Answer (score 1):

As directed by aerozeppelin I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 50331648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /home/htdocs/includes/database/query.inc on line 1857

So increasing the PHP memory limit is the cure; [this link](http://drupal.org/node/207036) is useful for that.

Answer (score 0):

In a file type

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

to know your php configuration. Here you can know the path of php error_log or type

```
<?php
print_r(error_get_last());
?>
```

to get the last error that occurred.

Comment: erro_log is set to `no value`
unfortunately my hosting provider does not seem to provide that feature
can I explicitly set it?

Comment: whats the output of <?php
print_r(error_get_last());
?>

Comment: I am getting no output (blank)

Comment: Try setting the error log using the following link, http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log. Without the error logs it would be a challenge to pin point the error.

Comment: So i guess increasing the php memory limit of your server fixed this problem. Right?

Comment: I am pretty Sure it would fix the problem... But my hosting provider doesnt allow me to increase its memory limit (currently set to 48 M and for soomth functioning it should be at least 64M ), so I am unable to fix this issue,uninstalling some modules may be the way.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is a late answer.But it will help for new people.

1. Try to add this in .htaccess file.

**php_value memory_limit 64M**

I hope this will help you to solve the Internal Server Error in Drupal 7

Comment: It's rather improbable that a php.ini in the root directory would be used from PHP.

Comment: yes adding php.ini is not a good method.But i could find it in few projects!